# CSS Dropdown menu isn't shown even though absolutely positioned because of overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overflow

I am trying to show a dropdown menu on hover, but I also have to apply an overflow: hidden to the parent element. The result is my dropdown, even though absolutely positioned, isn't visible (because of the overflow: hidden).

I reproduced the problem there: http://plnkr.co/edit/2rbaISwvzuKhyPEFpBKD?p=preview (you can hit Edit/Code edit to see the full source code)

(small sample)

```
#block-paddle-menu-display-first-level .menu_wrapper.level-2 {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#block-paddle-menu-display-first-level .has-children:hover .menu_wrapper.level-2 {
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Under the "Hover Here -..." list-item, there's a nested ul which should be shown on hover..

**requirements**

- The overflow: hidden on the parent is required for the arrows/sliding effect to work (it doesn't work perfectly on the test case but ignore that for now)
- We need the menu background color to expand on the whole page

Related Questions but not 100% identical: [Is it possible to see content that goes outside a container's dimensions when the container is set to Overflow hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780209/is-it-possible-to-see-content-that-goes-outside-a-containers-dimensions-when-th)

Comment: do you want overflow:hidden on the list-item ?

Comment: @"close"rs - explain why

Comment: @RahulSambari I want my dropdown to work.

Comment: i can see data when hovered ..called ypsilon mu etc

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/2rbaISwvzuKhyPEFpBKD/ refresh. I had disabled the overflow:hidden (work in progress)

Comment: This structure: `<ul class="paddle-sub-nav" counter="1"><ul class="menu level-2">` is invalid html. This is not causing your problems, but it's not good either.

Comment: @Paulie_D took me an hour to recreate this dude! appreciate. You only need to figure out why the dropdown isn't showing. Use the inspector, boom.

Comment: @NicoO what's invalid? the custom counter attribute? It's added via JS. Having a UL inside a UL I guess.. Thanks.. I'll take into account

Comment: I don't **need** to do anything. If you make it harder for me (or anyone else) to help you then you limit the amount of help you're gonna get. - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Cool, I removed 4 css files that weren't necessary and  dozen of html classes on the divs. I still don't think I'll get much help cause this isn't a noob question;)

Answer (score 0):

```
block-paddle-menu-display-first-level{ overflow:visible;}
```

remove float from the li and add `display:inline-block;` Work your way from that point.

Comment: That's a below the average answer. You can't drop one line of CSS and say "work your way from that point". Elaborate and I'll upvote.

Comment: The answer I gave u fixes the problem YOU ASKED. The fact that on hover your whole bar glitches, isn't in this question. It was a polite way of telling you to fix your code. (And yes those 2 lines of code WILL fix your problem)

Comment: Check the plunk again. The dropdown like every other dropdown on the planet should be positioned absolutely. You obviously checked the wrong plunk version while I was working on it.

Comment: And no, your answer doesn't fix the problem. I just tried it on the plunk itself.

Comment: Ok...I just did...modified in firebug what I just said, and i can see the dropdown. (no one said to remove position absolute...)

Comment: Could you go to my plunk, click on Fork, add your code, send the url back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62805/discussion-between-gho-and-george-katsanos).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move the navigation bar inside the content container - and move the overflow: hidden to an element higher in the DOM - this way we ensure the height is enough for the dropdown to be shown, while still hiding the content that overflows the horizontal axis...